# applicationContext in Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, config

is possible access the applicationContext in the config file?!

What I`m trying to do is get the full path(server path) for my app!

Pretty much I want is:

```
/usr/tomcat/myapp/web-inf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If @Ben's getRealPath() solution does not do the trick, try to piece together absolute path based on catalina base property:

```
def path = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + 'relative/path/to/app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question but I guess your are trying to retrieve the URL of your web application similar to this one: `http://localhost:8080/myawesomeapp`. `Config.groovy` has a built in option [grails.serverURL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.1%20Built%20in%20options) but this doesn't give you the web application subcontext. The result would be `http://localhost:8080`. I am not aware of a different option that would also give you the full web app context URL.

Alternatively, you can always use a method like this in your Grails controller that would give you the full web app URL:

```
def getContextUrl(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    String scheme = httpServletRequest.scheme
    String serverName = httpServletRequest.serverName
    int serverPort = httpServletRequest.serverPort
    String contextPath = httpServletRequest.contextPath

    def url = new StringBuilder()
    url <<= '://'
    url <<= serverName

    if(serverPort && serverPort != 80) {
        url <<= ':'
        url <<= serverPort
    }

    url.toString()
}
```

Comment: For that you could use [javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath(java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)).